# Не отображается header

Tags: html, css, header

```css
.header {
  height: 101px;
  weight: 100%;
  background: url(img/header_bg.png);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Обои</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>

    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Хочу использовать картинку для отображения HEADER, в чем проблема?

Comment: `weight` - wtf? `width` и не `.header`, а `header`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Путь к файлу указывайте в ковычках.
2. Вы указываете стиль для класса `header`, указывайте просто для элемента `header`(Без точки вначале).
3. Ширина элемента пишется как `width`.

```
<style>
    header {
        height: 101px;
        width: 100%;
        background: url('Путь к файлу');
    }
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Обои</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <header>

    </header>
</div>
</body>
```